# Is in Python anything like in Java platform.exit() to leave the program

Tags: python, python-3

I got a Button and when the Button was tapped it runs a function.
Till here I got everything ready. And now my question I will close the program correct like in the title. Is in Python anything like in Java the platform.exit() function? Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

Or to set a bad exit code

```
import sys
sys.exit(2)
```

Or with a message

```
import sys
sys.exit('something very bad went wrong')
```